# How to find Number of Occurences of Slash from a strings

Tags: excel, vba

How can I find the number of occurrences of the forward slash character ( / ) within a string using an Excel VBA macro?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use the below function, as in `count = CountChrInString(yourString, "/")`.

```
'''
''' Returns the count of the specified character in the specified string.
'''
Public Function CountChrInString(Expression As String, Character As String) As Long
'
' ? CountChrInString("a/b/c", "/")
'  2
' ? CountChrInString("a/b/c", "\")
'  0
' ? CountChrInString("//////", "/")
'  6
' ? CountChrInString(" a / b / c ", "/")
'  2
' ? CountChrInString("a/b/c", " / ")
'  0
'
    Dim iResult As Long
    Dim sParts() As String

    sParts = Split(Expression, Character)

    iResult = UBound(sParts, 1)

    If (iResult = -1) Then
    iResult = 0
    End If

    CountChrInString = iResult

End Function
```

Comment: Not a big fan of hungarian notations, but thanks for the added comments :-)

Comment: There are two different kinds of Hungarian Notation. This is actually Systems Hungarian, the most dominant one, and _not_ the original concept which initially also was called Apps Hungarian. There's a big difference between them, one you can read about here: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/

Answer (score 74):

Old question, but I thought I would add to the quality of the answer by an answer I found at an excel forum. Apparently the count can also be found using.

```
    count =Len(string)-Len(Replace(string,"/",""))
```

Full credit for the answer goes to the original author at:http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=45651

Comment: Ha!  I just thought of that one, but I came here to see if there was a better solution.

Comment: The beauty of this, is that you can easily use it in formulas, without VBA, using `SUBSTITUTE()`

Comment: A more generic answer would be to have `count = (Len(string)-Len(Replace(string,"/",""))) / len("/")`. Then you can also count strings with a length of more than 1.

Answer (score 29):

```
Function CountOfChar(str as string, character as string) as integer
      CountOfChar = UBound(Split(str, character))
End Function
```

Comment: This is the best one. You can look for grouped sets of characters as well.

Comment: @Vityata I don't follow. This `ubound(split("x   x "," "))` returns 4, which is what you want (string is x[space][space][space]x[space]). Can you provide a working example of how it would not work?

Comment: @mountainclimber - actually it works, sry, I was thinking about something else - in `Replace()` the spaces are united to one.

Comment: You are missing one line of code: in case of `str = ""`, the result is `-1`. Also I would name parameters `inThis` and `countThis`, because second isn't limited to character, it works also as longer string.

Comment: I agree with @miroxlav that naming convention is a bit off, but this is by far the best answer. And i don't think is missing anything, you can use the `-1` result as well in your code (i.e. `if result = -1 then...`). Obviously if you don't care about the `-1` then you can add the "missing line", but is a matter of preference.

Comment: may be "worksheetfunction.max(0,UBound(Split(str, character)))"

Answer (score 2):

BTW, if you are into performance, the following is 20% faster than using split or replace to determine the count:

```
Private Function GetCountOfChar( _
  ByRef ar_sText As String, _
  ByVal a_sChar As String _
) As Integer
  Dim l_iIndex As Integer
  Dim l_iMax As Integer
  Dim l_iLen As Integer

  GetCountOfChar = 0
  l_iMax = Len(ar_sText)
  l_iLen = Len(a_sChar)
  For l_iIndex = 1 To l_iMax
    If (Mid(ar_sText, l_iIndex, l_iLen) = a_sChar) Then 'found occurrence
      GetCountOfChar = GetCountOfChar + 1
      If (l_iLen > 1) Then l_iIndex = l_iIndex + (l_iLen - 1) 'if matching more than 1 char, need to move more than one char ahead to continue searching
    End If
  Next l_iIndex
End Function
```

Comment: At least with long enough strings for the performance differences to really matter, using this technique to iterate over every character will always be slower than either the split or replace techniques.  Usually substantially slower.  I'm curious how you arrived at that figure, @user9338905?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a single line version for use when you don't want to call a separate function.  It's just a compressed version of the CountChrInString and some others above.

```
? UBound(Split("abcabcabc", "cd"), 1)
```

This will return 0. If you change "cd" to "ab" it returns 3. It also works with variables. Note that if the string being checked (abcabc...) is empty it WILL return -1.

Answer (score 1):

I like Santhosh Divakar's answer, so I expanded on it to account for the possibility when you want to check for more than just a single character by dividing the result by the length of the search characters, like this:

```
Function Num_Characters_In_String(Input_String As String, Search_Character As String) As Integer
'Returns the number of times a specified character appears in an input string by replacing them with an empty string
'   and comparing the two string lengths. The final result is then divided by the length of the Search_Character to
'   provide for multiple Search Characters.

    Num_Characters_In_String = (Len(Input_String) - Len(Replace(Input_String, Search_Character, ""))) / Len(Search_Character)

End Function
```

As an example, the result of

```
Num_Characters_In_String("One/Two/Three/Four//", "//")
```

gives you 1, because there is only a double slash at the end of the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

As noted, performance and memory utilisation are unlikely to be concerns, but in cases of reading large files into a single string it may be. @Alexis_Martial attempted this but a) with an unnecessary `goto` statement b) not taking the length of the string being searched for into account.

```
Public Function Occurences(ByRef s As String, ByRef substr As String, Optional ByVal compareMethod As VbCompareMethod = vbBinaryCompare) As Long
Dim idx As Long
Dim sublen As Long
    sublen = Len(substr)
    idx = 1
    Occurences = -1
    Do
        Occurences = Occurences + 1
        idx = InStr(idx, s, substr, compareMethod) + sublen
    Loop While idx > sublen
End Function
```

Comment: Clean and optimal by using substr length, nice!

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy solution for VBA Excel Macros.

```
Function CharCount(str As String, chr As String) As Integer
     CharCount = Len(str) - Len(Replace(str, chr, ""))
End Function
```

Comment: And what make your answer different from Santhosh Divakar's?

Answer (score 0):

If you are into performance and minimal memory use, both Split and Len/Replace solutions are not optimal.

Here my proposal

```
Public Function CountOf(ByRef s As String, ByRef substr As String, Optional ByVal compareMethod As VbCompareMethod = vbBinaryCompare) As Integer

Dim c As Integer
Dim idx As Integer

NEXT_MATCH:
idx = InStr(idx + 1, s, substr, compareMethod)
If idx > 0 Then
    c = c + 1
    GoTo NEXT_MATCH:
End If

CountOf = c + 1
End Function
```

And here are the performance, running each option 1,000,000 times on a simple case and one case with more entries:

```
5.828ms       Empty Loop
s = '0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9', separator = ','
1.882s         UBound(Split) algo
2.537s         Len/Replace() algo
760.710ms      CountOf()

s = '[ABC],long, longer,sdfgshttsdbghhgsssssshsdhhhhhhhhhhhh,,,,777777777777777777777777777777,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,LAST', separator = ','
18.330s        UBound(Split) algo
21.743s        Len/Replace() algo
9.544s         CountOf()
```

So overall around 2x to 3x faster even while CountOf was a function call while Split and Len/Replace where directly in the loop code.

Also note that the performance ratio keep stable when the number of items and their length increase, as show below (test done with only 1,000 iterations)

```
s ="[ABC],long,longer,sdfgshttsdbghhgsssssshsdhhhhhhhhhhhh,,,,777777777777777777777,Repeat(1000,"A...Z"),LAST', separator = ','
232.160ms      UBound(Split): 1033
325.367ms      Len/Replace(): 1033
113.658ms      CountOf(): 1033
```

Comment: True, but for most cases only a few counts are done. Thus, difference will be some µS. More importantly, you won't get many credits from your code friends for using a _GoTo_ in place of a normal loop.

Answer (score -1):

Yet another good option is to use RegExp. I tried the following in Microsoft Word, but I'm sure it works about the same in Excel.

In a Word document with 190,000 words and 2,400 instances of a three-letter word, the following function took an average of 0.938 seconds to count them (I include a Sub below it to conveniently display the time):

```
Function RegExpCount(WholeString As String, Substring As String) As Long

Dim MatchCol As MatchCollection

With New RegExp
    .Pattern = Substring
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = False 'or True, depending on your needs
    .MultiLine = False
    Set MatchCol = .Execute(WholeString)
End With

RegExpCount = MatchCol.count

End Function

Sub CountInstances()
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
'Remember time when macro starts
  StartTime = Timer

Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = ActiveDocument.Range
Debug.Print "The number of times 'your substring' appears in this document is: " & RegExpCount(Rng.Text, "your substring")

'Calculate how many seconds code took to run
  SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)

'Notify user in seconds
  MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation

End Sub
```

It always output 2,400 correctly. Alexis Martial's CountOf function took the same amount of time, as did Rick_R's UBound(Split) command. They all output the same count in about 0.92-0.95 seconds.

Comment: Be careful with this one, it doesn't do what you say it does! This solution will return the number of matches of the RegEx pattern you pass in as `Substring`. For instance, passing "\w+" as `Substring` will not count the number of occurrences of "\w+" but rather the number of words in your `WholeString`. This is of course a more powerful functionality, but it's not what you say it does. To actually count the number of occurrences you have to escape all RegEx "Special Characters" in `Substring` first. These are: `.`, `+`, `*`, `?`, `^`, `$`, `(`, `)`, `[`, `]`, `{`, `}`, `|`, ``\``.

Comment: Escaping a RegEx "Special Character" can be done by placing a ``\`` in front of it. So you first have to edit your `Substring` with an expression like this: `Substring = replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(Substring, "\", "\\") ".", "\."), "+", "\+"), "*", "\*"), "?", "\?"), "^", "\^"), "$", "\$"), "(", "\("), ")", "\)"), "[", "\["), "]", "\]"), "{", "\{"), "}", "\}"), "|", "\|")` for the code to do what you say it does, which is count the number of occurrences of `Substring` in `WholeString`.

Comment: Yes, I know. I guess I'm used to escaping regex metacharacters as I come across them, but every user won't be aware of that. Instead of saying three times that the function doesn't do what I say it does, it would be more accurate to say it does what I say it does except that you have to escape the 14 RegExp metacharacters.

Comment: Btw, it never occurred to me to nest Replace commands and strings like that. That's neat.

Comment: Saying it doesn't do what you say it does is perfectly accurate. I'm in no way meaning to criticize you personally, this is just meant as a warning for people who are potentially going to use your code because code from Stackoverflow gets copied a lot, and one has to be aware of that... I like that you compared the performance of the Regex method to the other methods, it adds information to this thread! And about the nested replaces, yeah it doesn't really make for the most readable code, but in the comment, it was the only option I saw :)