# How do I count the number of times a string appears within another string in VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

How do I count the number of times one string appears within another in Access VBA? For example, how would I count how many times "the" occurs in "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you are ok with substrings/case sensitivity

```
matches = (len(lookin) - len(replace$(lookin, find, ""))) / len(find)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify the function with far less variables and avoid the usage of For by the following function.

```
Public Function getOccuranceCount(Expression As String, Find As String) As Long
'*******************************************************************************
'Code Courtesy of
'  Paul Eugin
'
'   Input  - Expression, the String to check
'            Find, the String pattern to be checked for
'   Output - The number of occurance of the Find String in the Expression String
'   Usage  - getOccuranceCount("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.","saw")
'               0
'            getOccuranceCount("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.","the")
'               2
'*******************************************************************************
On Error GoTo errDisplay
    Dim strArr() As String, i As Long
    strArr = Split(Expression, Find)
    getOccuranceCount = UBound(strArr)

errExit:
    Exit Function
errDisplay:
    MsgBox "The following error has occured while trying to get the count." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
           "Error (" & Err.Number & ") - " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Contact the DB Admin."
Resume errExit
End Function
```

The function will Split it into an array then all you need is the Count of the Boundaries. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim lookin As String
Dim tofind As String
lookin = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
tofind = "the "

Dim r As Object, matches
Set r = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

r.Pattern = tofind
r.IgnoreCase = True
r.Multiline = False
r.Global = True
Set matches = r.Execute(lookin)
```

matches finds two hits. One at index = 0 and one at index = 31.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function, which uses InStr:

```
Function CountStringOccurances(strStringToCheck As String, strValueToCheck As String) As Integer
'Purpose: Counts the number of times a string appears in another string.
On Error GoTo ErrorMessage
    Dim intStringPosition As Integer
    Dim intCursorPosition As Integer
    CountStringOccurances = 0
    intCursorPosition = 1
    For i = 0 To Len(strStringToCheck)
        intStringPosition = InStr(intCursorPosition, strStringToCheck, strValueToCheck)
        If intStringPosition = 0 Then
            Exit Function
        Else
            CountStringOccurances = CountStringOccurances + 1
            intCursorPosition = intStringPosition + Len(strValueToCheck)
        End If
    Next i
    Exit Function
ErrorMessage:
MsgBox "The database has generated an error. Please contact the database administrator, quoting the following error message: '" & Err.Description & "'", vbCritical, "Database Error"
End
End Function
```

The function returns the position of your value within the string. If that's 0, it exits and returns the number. If it returns a positive value (and it will if the value is present), then it adds one to the number of occurances, and then checks again, moving its starting position to just after the previous occurance. This function is case insenstive.

Using the examples above:

```
CountStringOccurances("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.","the")
```

would return 2.

Comment: You asked the question and you answered it too? I am a bit confused.

Comment: You can answer your own questions if you have a bit of code you want to share in a Q&A style; but thanks for your additional answer.

Comment: Okay ! I am very new to this site, so still trying to understand how this works. I saw the question and answered it, came back after a few hours to see; that the answer you gave looked like you are talking to another person (You can use this function, which uses InStr:). Checked again, both were the same name. Ha Ha ! Anyway, glad to suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Split in the same solution as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260982/how-to-find-number-of-occurences-of-slash-from-a-strings) has. It's the tidiest solution that I've seen so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub KombiAssiDep10_AfterUpdate()
On Error GoTo Problem
'=================================================

    str1 = Me.CombiAssiDepartment1.Column(0)   'Value Searched
    str2 = Me.TextResponsibleDepartment.Value  'A place to search
    If (Len(str2) - Len(Replace(LCase(str2), LCase(str1), ""))) / Len(str1) > 1 Then
    
    MsgBox "This department has already been designated!"
    End If


'=================================================
Problem:

End

End Sub
```