# Text to row VBA codes error in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am using these codes for text to row purpose but i am not able to convert it after certain Number of rows in Col B. whereas it is working fine for col c and d. one more thing if i am removing the on error resume next then i am getting subscript out of range error. please help me on these errors.

[image]

Expected Output for given input:

[image: output]

---

Code:

```
Sub Main()
On Error Resume Next
Columns("B:B").NumberFormat = "@"
Dim i As Long, c As Long, r As Range, v As Variant

For i = 1 To Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    v = Split(Range("B" & i), ",")
    c = c + UBound(v) + 1
Next i

For i = 2 To c
    Set r = Range("B" & i)
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Split(r, ",")
    Dim j As Long
    r = arr(0)
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr)
        Rows(r.Row + j & ":" & r.Row + j).Insert shift:=xlDown
        r.Offset(j, 0) = arr(j)
        r.Offset(j, -1) = r.Offset(0, -1)
        r.Offset(j, 1) = r.Offset(0, 1)
    Next j
Next i

Columns("C:C").NumberFormat = "@"
For i = 1 To Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    v = Split(Range("C" & i), ",")
    c = c + UBound(v) + 1
Next i
For i = 2 To c
    Set r = Range("C" & i)
    arr = Split(r, ",")
    r = arr(0)
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr)
    r.Offset(j, 0) = arr(j)
    r.Offset(j, 1) = r.Offset(0, 1)
    Next j
Next i
Columns("D:D").NumberFormat = "@"
For i = 1 To Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    v = Split(Range("D" & i), ",")
    c = c + UBound(v) + 1
Next i
For i = 2 To c
    Set r = Range("D" & i)

    arr = Split(r, ",")
    r = arr(0)
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr)
    r.Offset(j, 0) = arr(j)
    r.Offset(j, 1) = r.Offset(0, 1)
    Next j
Next i
Columns("E:E").NumberFormat = "@"

For i = 1 To Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    v = Split(Range("E" & i), ",")
    c = c + UBound(v) + 1
Next i
For i = 2 To c
    Set r = Range("E" & i)

    arr = Split(r, ",")
    r = arr(0)
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr)
    r.Offset(j, 0) = arr(j)
    r.Offset(j, 1) = r.Offset(0, 1)
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey check in post

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that works.

Before:
Inv Hours   Bill    am  Loc
1   10,12   1,2 10,24   BANG,KOL
2   1,2,3   1,2,3   1,4,9   A,B,C

After:
Inv Hours   Bill    am  Loc
1   10  1   10  BANG
1   12  2   24  KOL
2   1   1   1   A
2   2   2   4   B
2   3   3   9   C

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()

Columns("B:B").NumberFormat = "@"
Dim i As Long, c As Long, r As Range, v As Variant

For i = 1 To Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    v = Split(Range("B" & i), ",")
    c = c + UBound(v) + 1
Next i

For i = 2 To c
    Set r = Range("B" & i)
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Split(r, ",")
    Dim j As Long
    r = arr(0)
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr)
        Rows(r.Row + j & ":" & r.Row + j).Insert shift:=xlDown
        r.Offset(j, 0) = arr(j)
        r.Offset(j, -1) = r.Offset(0, -1)
        r.Offset(j, 1) = r.Offset(0, 1)
    Next j
Next i


Columns("C:C").NumberFormat = "@"
For i = 1 To Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    v = Split(Range("C" & i), ",")
    'c = c + UBound(v) + 1
Next i
For i = 2 To c
    Set r = Range("C" & i)
    arr = Split(r, ",")
    r = arr(0)
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr)
    r.Offset(j, 0) = arr(j)
    r.Offset(j, 1) = r.Offset(0, 1)
    Next j
Next i
Columns("D:D").NumberFormat = "@"

For i = 1 To Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    v = Split(Range("D" & i), ",")
    'c = c + UBound(v) + 1
Next i
For i = 2 To c
    Set r = Range("D" & i)

    arr = Split(r, ",")
    r = arr(0)
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr)
    r.Offset(j, 0) = arr(j)
    r.Offset(j, 1) = r.Offset(0, 1)
    Next j
Next i
Columns("E:E").NumberFormat = "@"

For i = 1 To Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    v = Split(Range("E" & i), ",")
    'c = c + UBound(v) + 1
Next i
For i = 2 To c
    Set r = Range("E" & i)

    arr = Split(r, ",")
    r = arr(0)
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr)
    r.Offset(j, 0) = arr(j)
    r.Offset(j, 1) = r.Offset(0, 1)
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Gerald, If i remove C then it will not split

Comment: oh yes, you may have to reset to 0 the c before each column. So do a c=0 before.
I would put the code of each column in a specific function.

Comment: actually, it won't fix. The variable names do not help to understand what you do. As long as you create a new line only for the first column, I assume you expect to have the number of data to split the same for each column.
So by just commenting the computation of c value on all columns except the first one it works well.

Answer (score 0):

So here is a code that works (reposted here as I guess you will close your other question):

```
Option Explicit

Sub SplitByRows()
Dim Col As Long, LastRow As Long, ColParts() As String
Dim i, a, k As Long
Dim StringNo As String
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow
    k = CountChrInString(Cells(i, 2).Value, ",")
    StringNo = Cells(i, 1).Value
        For a = 1 To k
            Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value & "," & StringNo
        Next a
Next i

For Col = 1 To 5 'Column A to Column C
    ColParts = Split(Join(Application.Transpose(Range(Cells(2, Col), Cells(LastRow, Col))), ","), ",")
    With Cells(2, Col).Resize(UBound(ColParts) + 1)
    .NumberFormat = "_(* #,##0.00_);_(* (#,##0.00);_(* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
    .Value = Application.Transpose(ColParts)
    End With
Next

End Sub


Public Function CountChrInString(Expression As String, Character As String) As Long

    Dim iResult As Long
    Dim sParts() As String

    sParts = Split(Expression, Character)

    iResult = UBound(sParts, 1)

    If (iResult = -1) Then
    iResult = 0
    End If

    CountChrInString = iResult

End Function
```

All I did was adding some "," to the first column as well at the beginning of your code.

For this I needed to count the amount of "," in the cell of the second column. 
  This was done with the function from this page: [How to find Number of Occurences of Slash from a strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260982/how-to-find-number-of-occurences-of-slash-from-a-strings)

After that your code just did the rest ;)