# Excel Text to row Code Error

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

[image]

Hi Here it is expected input and expected output

I am using these code but in first column instead of coming same as output its just giving serial no. 
[image]

```
Sub SplitByRows()
Dim Col As Long, LastRow As Long, ColParts() As String
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
For Col = 2 To 5 'Column A to Column C
ColParts = Split(Join(Application.Transpose(Range(Cells(2, Col), 
Cells(LastRow, Col))), ","), ",")
With Cells(2, Col).Resize(UBound(ColParts) + 1)
  .NumberFormat = "_(* #,##0.00_);_(* (#,##0.00);_(* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
  .Value = Application.Transpose(ColParts)
End With
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: How is this different from your [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51982062/text-to-row-vba-codes-error-in-excel) ? The code appears different but the questions seems the same (on quick skim - sorry if I got it wrong).

Comment: Why is this tagged with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Well, 1st of all, you start with column B, not A:

```
For Col = 2 To 5 'Column A to Column C
```

Shoul be:

```
For Col = 1 To 5 'Column A to Column C
```

Then, as I understand your code, you need column A values to be:

> ```
> 1,1
> 2,2,2
> ```

Answer (score 0):

So here is a code that works:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SplitByRows()
Dim Col As Long, LastRow As Long, ColParts() As String
Dim i, a, k As Long
Dim StringNo As String
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow
    k = CountChrInString(Cells(i, 2).Value, ",")
    StringNo = Cells(i, 1).Value
        For a = 1 To k
            Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value & "," & StringNo
        Next a
Next i

For Col = 1 To 5 'Column A to Column C
    ColParts = Split(Join(Application.Transpose(Range(Cells(2, Col), Cells(LastRow, Col))), ","), ",")
    With Cells(2, Col).Resize(UBound(ColParts) + 1)
    .NumberFormat = "_(* #,##0.00_);_(* (#,##0.00);_(* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
    .Value = Application.Transpose(ColParts)
    End With
Next

End Sub


Public Function CountChrInString(Expression As String, Character As String) As Long

    Dim iResult As Long
    Dim sParts() As String

    sParts = Split(Expression, Character)

    iResult = UBound(sParts, 1)

    If (iResult = -1) Then
    iResult = 0
    End If

    CountChrInString = iResult

End Function
```

All I did was adding some "," to the first column as well at the beginning of your code.

For this I needed to count the amount of "," in the cell of the second column. 
  This was done with the function from this page: [How to find Number of Occurences of Slash from a strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260982/how-to-find-number-of-occurences-of-slash-from-a-strings)

After that your code just did the rest ;)

Comment: Where did you get an error? Or what is not working on your excel?

Comment: In 1st column the invoice no. is not getting repeated

Comment: The first Column is the Column "A"? Did you check if the function works for you? What about the first part alone (the loop with "i")?