# Get count of number of spaces in string using regex

Tags: regex, vb.net

I need to count the number of spaces between words in a string. I would like to use regex because I think it would require the least amount of code.

Below is the code that I have tried. Sample text string:This is a string I am using for test.  This string has 7 spaces. I would hope that SC (below in code) would display 7, but it doesn't, it shows 1. I suspect the problem is length instead of count. How can I fix this.

```
 Dim match As Match = Regex.Match(myString, "[ ]+")    
 Dim SC As Integer = match.Length 
 TextBox1.Text = SC
```

Comment: What is your sample string? Is it _"This is a string I am using for test"_? That string has 8 spaces, not 7.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find Number of Occurences of Slash from a strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260982/how-to-find-number-of-occurences-of-slash-from-a-strings). Just use a space instead of a slash.

Comment: Try using `.Matches` instead of `Match` and count each space instead by matching the pattern: `" "` (`"(space)"`). Then you should be able to do `match.Count` and that will return the number of spaces. I'm not sure on the exact vb syntax, but it works in c#

Comment: Try count = text.Split(" ").Length -1.  Seems to work for me.  And a lot simpler than using regex expressions

Comment: Hursey, your solution is nice and simple. The reason I was looking for a regex solution is because I am trying to increase my knowledge and experience of regex. You deserve a solution vote but I don't know how to do it now that I already did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this way of counting the spaces in your expression:

```
Dim sampleInput = "XX, VV, A01"
Dim results = Regex.Replace(sampleInput, "[^ ]", "")
Console.WriteLine("Line: {0}", results.Length)
```

Get rid of anything that is not an space and then count the length of the result. You may also use `\S` instead of `[^ ]`

[**.NET Fiddle Demo**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NsBGHl)

```
imports System
imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
            Dim sampleInput = "XX, VV, A01"
            Dim results = Regex.Replace(sampleInput, "[^ ]", "")
           Console.WriteLine("Line: {0}", results.Length)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Nice and clean. I like it. The actual line of code I used is:   Dim SC As Integer = Regex.Replace(myString, "[^ ]+", "").Length