# VBA counting substrings in a string across a range

Tags: excel, vba, string, substring

I have been working on a worksheet in Excel and im trying to get accurate number of sub strings within a string across a range.  Im using columns C and D that have text them im adding the following code to get a number of the occurrences of particular words and total them in column H by using a public function. I cannot get the code to span a range and bring back the answer.  Maybe there is a better way.?

```
Option Compare Text

Function CountString(FullString As String, PartialString As String) As Integer

Dim cnt As Integer

cnt = 0
For i = 1 To Len(FullString)

If Mid(FullString, i, Len(PartialString)) = PartialString Then

cnt = cnt + 1

End If
Next i

CountString = cnt

End Function
```

Comment: Can you better explain what you mean with "I cannot get the code to span a range and bring back the answer."?

Comment: Apologies, i meant as in this applies to one cell where as i want to apply the sub string search to both C8:D8 for example and find the word across a range.

Comment: Then, check my code, which should be exactly that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the credit for the next code must go to @Mark. But, if on some installations the code returns wrong, please use the next variant:

```
Function CountString(FullString As String, PartialString As String) As Long
    CountString = UBound(Split(FullString, PartialString))
    If UBound(Split("x", "x")) = 2 Then CountString = CountString - 1
End Function
```

The way or function using to count total occurrences in a range, would be the next:

```
Sub countStringsInRange()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, TotCount As Long, cel As Range, strSearch As String
   
   strSearch = "Dog"
   Set sh = ActiveSheet ' use here your sheet
   
   Set rng = sh.Range("C8:D8") 'use here whatever range you need
   For Each cel In rng
        TotCount = TotCount + CountString(cel.Value, strSearch)
   Next
   Debug.Print TotCount
End Sub
```

After editing:

The next function is able to also process arrays (it works for strings, too):

```
Function CountStringArr(FullString As String, PartialString As Variant) As Long
   Dim El As Variant, iCount As Long
    If IsArray(PartialString) Then
        For Each El In PartialString
            iCount = iCount + UBound(Split(FullString, El))
        Next
        CountStringArr = iCount
    Else
        CountStringArr = UBound(Split(FullString, PartialString))
    End If
End Function
```

It can be called as in the next example:

```
Dim x As String
  x = "CatDogCatDogCatDogCatDogCatDogCatDogCatDogCatDogCatDogCatDog"
  Debug.Print CountStringArr(x, Array("Dog", "Cat")) 'it returns 20
  Debug.Print CountStringArr(x, "Dog")  'it returns 10
```

And it can be called from a range in the next way:

```
    Sub countStringsInRangeBis()
       Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, TotCount As Long, cel As Range, strSearch As Variant
       
       strSearch = Split("Dog,Cat", ",") 'or Array("Dog", "Cat")
       Set sh = ActiveSheet ' use here your sheet
       
       Set rng = sh.Range("C8:D8") 'use here whatever range you need
       For Each cel In rng
            TotCount = TotCount + CountStringArr(cel.Value, strSearch)
       Next
       Debug.Print TotCount
    End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry not quite understanding here i was trying to apply the process to a range e.g. C8:D8 rather than to a single cell but when i try to do so it only works on a single Cell C8 for example.  Be gentle, my head is mashed now. :-)

Comment: I also messed around using InStr for hours and hours yesterday but only give me a count of one per cell no matter how many occurrences of the sub string there was in a cell.  Grrrrrrr

Comment: @vbvirg20: Do you need **the total count on the total range**? Not for each cell value? You presented only the function counting the occurrences in a string...

Comment: @vbvirg20:  Please, check the updated code, showing how to count the occurrences in a range. Please confirm that it does what you need.

Comment: I thought I figured it out, but I didn't. Could you share what the second line in the function is all about.

Comment: @vbvirg20:  That line does nothing for 99 computers from 100, but if you look to an above comment (Corrado Barbero), initially I thought it was you, complained that in his case the function (without the added line) returns one more occurrence. I think he hase `Option Base 1` on top of the module code. But I added the line in discussion in order to also avoid such a situation, if any... But, I did not understand the next issue:  **Does the code do what you need, or not**?

Comment: @vbvirg20:  The meaning of that line would be: If the calculated result for a string which must be 1 is 2 (for the case I mentioned above), then decreases the calculated result with one unit... In other words, it is a kind of calibration.

Comment: It works like a dream, thank you so much for your time and help  :-)

Comment: One other question, if i wanted to change this to an array of words would i just change the function from Fullstring as string and partialstring as string to variants and change strsearch  =  arrary ("Dog", "Cat")??

Comment: @vbvirg20: There would be two approaches: 1. Send each array element to the function as it is, or 2. I can adapt the function to accept an array as argument. What do you prefer?

Comment: @vbvirg20: But, do you need to count both of them together. Is my understanding correct? Otherwise, how would you interpret the eventual array to be returned? And now I can see that you changed your mind and un-ticked the **accepted answer** check box. Is it something wrong with the answer as it was, referring to your question?

Comment: @vbvirg20: You tried editing my answer, trying to insert your (wrong) code doesn't working. This is not a normal way of acting. If you have something you do not understand, or you suppose that the above code has a bug, please edit your question, post the code you appreciate is not well processed by the code and tag me here to help. You did not confirm, at least, that the counting must be done for both together, even if I asked about that. Your code should raise an error at the line `TotCount = "0"`, since `TotCount` is declared `As Long`... No need to **select** anything in your code!

Comment: Ah right apologies absolutely my fault and thanks for the advice. I will go and Test accordingly.

Comment: I tested using the original code, but could not get it to work with the correct range e.g C2:E4000, if there was 2 strings that said dog in each row as it got further down the spreadsheet when i cannot find anything just went to negative numbering.  Im thinking user error on my behalf.

Answer (score 4):

```
A = "CatDogCatDogCatDogCatDogCatDogCatDogCatDogCatDogCatDogCatDog"
Msgbox UBound(Split(A, "Dog"))
```

This counts how many times dog appears in the string by using `dog` as a delimiter then counting how many elements in the array.

---

**edit**

Application of technique for OP:

```
Function CountString(FullString As String, PartialString As String) As Integer
CountString = UBound(Split(FullString, PartialString))
End Function
```

---

**Edit 2**

```
Set regEx = New RegExp
A="DogCatDogCatDogCatDogCatDogCatDogCatDogCatDogCatDogCatDogCat"
regEx.Pattern = "dog" 
regEx.IgnoreCase = True
regEx.Global = True
Set MyMatches = regEx.Execute(A)
Msgbox MyMatches.Count
```

This counts the delimiter.

You have `.test` which returns true/false, `.Execute` which returns a collections of matches, and `.replace` which has many uses including replace and extracting parts of files.

Comment: But this will answer 11 instead of 10 and 1 instead of 0... should you remove the +1? :-)

Comment: @Corrado Barbero: It shouldn't... Split returns a zero based array. I wanted to post exactly the same approach, but I found this answer. Do you have other `Option` declarations on top of your module? `Option Base1`? I would suggest you to test the function in a new test module. But if in your (peculiar) case it returns in this way, you simply adapt: `CountString = UBound(Split(FullString, PartialString)) - 1`...

Comment: Wait a sec, my comment regarding the "+1" was for a version of the code above which ended with "+1" which has now been edited to remove it.

Comment: I am confused, the solution above (CatDogCat) works without adding 1, even if split creates a 0 based array, because an additional empty element is created at the end of the array... so when finding 10 "splitters", 11 elements are created, 0 to 10... I tested in a new empty file without any options

Comment: It actually makes sense, since a new "splitter" is considered to be followed by some content. But it's very confusing.

Comment: @Corrado Barbero: Not really... If you have two elements separated by comma, when split them like in the function, **not the array element are counted**! The interval between the elements is counted, because the string separator must be returned... :)

Comment: Thanks FaneDuru, I am a bit the stubborn type... you mean that if we would be counting the elements we would need to add 1 due to the array being zero based, while since we are counting the separators... we don't have to. Is it?

Comment: @Corrado Barbero: Yes, it is. But, if you do not tag me (@FaneDuru), I am not notified that you addressed to me...

Comment: @FaneDuru: newbie mistake :-)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of your loop, I would use one single statement like

```vb
Function CountString(FullString As String, PartialString As String) As Integer
   CountString = (Len(FullString) - Len(Replace(FullString, PartialString, ""))) / Len(PartialString)
End Function
```

(from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260982/how-to-find-number-of-occurences-of-slash-from-a-strings))

Answer (score -1):

### Count Substrings (In a Range)

```
Function countString(SourceString As Range, _
                     ByVal SubString As String, _
                     Optional ByVal ignoreCase As Boolean = False) _
         As Long
    
    Dim Data As Variant, Curr As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, Result As Long, iCase As Long
    
    If ignoreCase Then iCase = 1
    
    Data = SourceString.Value
    If IsArray(Data) Then
        GoSub CaseArray
    Else
        GoSub CaseValue
    End If
    
    countString = Result
    
    Exit Function

CaseArray:
    For i = 1 To UBound(Data)
        For j = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
            Curr = Data(i, j): GoSub countValue
        Next j
    Next i
    Return

CaseValue:
    Curr = Data: GoSub countValue
    Return

countValue:
    If Not IsError(Curr) Then
        Result = Result + UBound(Split(Curr, SubString, , iCase))
 '       Result = Result + (Len(Curr) _
               - Len(Replace(Curr, SubString, "", , , iCase))) / Len(SubString)
    End If
    Return
  
End Function
```