# Iterate over columns

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a vba macro that transforms text to columns, but this command is only capable of doing column by column.

```
    Columns("F:F").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("F1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

This code above works whell for one column, but i would like to do the command for the columns F to BL.

How can i do a For Loop to iterate over all the columns between F and BL?

Some sort of `For Columns in Range Do`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should give you an idea of what you can do.

Note that you don't need to select. And most of those option are probably set to their default value, making the code unecessary verbose. The macro recorder is nice but you might want to rework the result.

```
Sub quick_and_dirty()
    Dim cell As Range
    
    For Each cell In Range("F1:G1")
        cell.EntireColumn.TextToColumns Destination:=cell, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You are going to run into an issue with regard to overwriting existing data, so the route you want to follow is dependent on how you want to address that.

If you use AugustinLopez' method above, you'd want to make a handful of adjustments either way.

If you want to copy each row to a new sheet and then expand it, just add a "cell.EntireColumn copy xxx" step before the TextToColumns step and copy it to a new range.

If you want to add the necessary number of empty columns first, and presuming you have a variable number of commas through out the columns, it gets trickier and you'd need something like this (depending on your table size, some optimization for speed may be needed):

```
Sub DummyCode()

Dim cell As Range
Dim ColumnCount As Integer
Dim RangeOfInterest As Range
Dim CellStart As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim CommaCount As Integer


Set RangeOfInterest = Range("F1:BL1")


ColumnCount = RangeOfInterest.Columns.Count
CellStart = RangeOfInterest.Range("A1").Column

For i = CellStart + ColumnCount - 1 To CellStart Step -1 'you gotta go backwards to not mess up your count
    CommaCount = 0
    For Each cell In Intersect(Cells(1, i).EntireColumn, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        
    If InStr(1, cell.Value, ",") > 0 Then
        If CommaCount < (Len(cell.Value) - Len(Replace(cell.Value, ",", ""))) Then
            CommaCount = (Len(cell.Value) - Len(Replace(cell.Value, ",", "")))
            'credit for the above bit of cleverness goes to here:
            'http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=45651
            'via here
            'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260982/how-to-find-number-of-occurences-of-slash-from-a-strings
        End If
        
    End If
    
    For j = 1 To CommaCount
        Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Insert
    Next j
    
    Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.TextToColumns Destination:=Cells(1, i), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    
Next i

End Sub
```

good luck!