# Counting the matching substrings in range

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a workbook in which I need to count how many times the "St/" substring is present in a Range (Column Q). Note: I am interested in all the occurrences, not just the number of cells in which the substring is present. 
Here is the code I am trying to work with (based on the comment of Santhosh Divakar - https://stackoverflow.com/a/23357807/12536295), but I receive a runtime error (13) when running it. What am I missing / doing wrong?

```
Dim lastrow, q as Integer
lastrow = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown).Row
With Application
q = .SumProduct((Len(Range("Q1:Q" & lastrow)) - Len(.Substitute(Range("Q1:Q" & lastrow), "St/", ""))) / Len("St/"))
End With
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if the code below helps you:

```
Public Sub TestCount()
    lastrow = Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    strformula = "=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(Q1:Q" & lastrow & ")-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(Q1:Q" & lastrow & "),""/ST"","""")))/LEN(""/St"")"
    MsgBox Evaluate(strformula)
End Sub
```

Comment: Valid answer to OP; think search string has slash as last character "ST/", not "/ST". *Used evaluation in my post, too.*

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. The Evaluate method made it happen. Thanks shrivallabha.redij!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can count the number of characters, replace your "St/" with nothing and then count the characters again and divide by len("St/"). Here's an example.

```
'''your existing code
Dim lCount As Long
Dim lCount_After As Long
'''set a Range to column Q
Set oRng = Range("Q1:Q" & lRow_last)
'''turn that range into a string
sValues = CStr(Join(Application.Transpose(oRng.Value2)))
lCount = Len(sValues)
lCount_After = lCount - Len(Replace(sValues, "St/", ""))
lCount_After = lCount_After / 3

Debug.Print lCount_After
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using `ArrayToText()` function**

a) If you dispose of Excel version **MS365** you can shorten a prior string building by *evaluating* the tabular **`ARRAYTOTEXT()`**
formula to get a joined string of all rows at once *(complementing @Foxfire 's valid solution)*.

Note that it's necessary to insert the range address as string;
in order to *fully qualify the range reference* I use an additional `External:=True` argument.

b) VBA's `Split()` function eventually allows to return the number of found delimiters (e.g. "St/") via
`UBound()` function. It returns the upper boundary (i.e. the largest available subscript) for this
zero-based 1-dimensional split array.

Example: If there exist eight `St/` delimiters, the split array consists
of nine elements; as it is zero-based the first element has index `0`
and the last element gets identified by `8` which is already the wanted function result.

```
Function CountOccurrencies(rng As Range, Optional delim as String = "St/")
'a) get a final string (avoiding to join cells per row) 
    Dim txt As String
    txt = Evaluate("ArrayToText(" & rng.Address(False, False, External:=True) & ")")
'b) get number of delimiters 
    CountOccurrencies = UBound(Split(txt, delim))
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the cleanest one, but you can take all into arrays and split by `St/`. Size of that array would be how many coincidences you got:

```
Sub test()
Dim LR As Long
Dim MyText() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim q As Long

LR = Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ReDim Preserve MyText(1 To LR) As String

For i = 1 To LR Step 1
    MyText(i) = Range("Q" & i).Value
Next i

q = UBound(Split(Join(MyText, ""), "St/"))

Debug.Print q
Erase MyText
End Sub
```

[image]

The output i get is 8

Please, note **this code is case sensitive**.

Comment: Fine solution +:) Fyi might be interested in my complementary post via `ArrayToText`, but based on the same methodical approach. - *(Side note: would fully qualify range reference)*

Answer (score 1):

The TextJoin() function in Excel 2019+ is used:

```vb
Sub CalcSt()
    Const WHAT = "St/": Dim joined As String
    joined = WorksheetFunction.TextJoin("|", True, Columns("Q"))
    Debug.Print (Len(joined) - Len(Replace(joined, WHAT, ""))) / Len(WHAT)
End Sub
```